# Any way to monitor status of materialized views in dbt?

Tags: dbt

is any way to know the refresh status of materialized views? I want to figure out how to track if the materialized refresh was successful .

Comment: What database platform are you using? The answer is likely to be specific to that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Views, by definition, are not refreshed as such: they are always containing the latest data available in the source. E.g. if you were to query a staging model that is materialised as a view and looks like the following:

```sql
-- This is your staging model, materialised as a view
{{ config(materialized='view') }}

select * from {{ source('your_crm', 'orders') }}
```

You would get the freshest data from the source, even if it is an order (for the sake of the example) that was created 5min ago, as long as this order is already appearing in your source table.

So, long story short, you can always confirm this by querying any of your materialized views, and checking what data is available in their source.

Comment: Thank you! My specific question is if there is any way to track it? To see it the refresh failed or not. Or it'll always be successful?

Comment: There is no refresh per se. As long as the source refreshes are good, views’ data will be fresh as well.